# How disable validation Formik when clicking cancel button?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I'm using `Material-ui` with `Formik` and `Yup` for form validation, but I'm having trouble disabling form validation when clicking the cancel button. Tried using formik `resetForm` but it doesn't work!
Can you help me?

***By clicking the cancel button, it's doesn't work!***
[image]

Thank you for your help!

[image]

***Code***

```
import { Box, Button, Grid } from "@mui/material";
import { Field, Form, Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

import "./styles.css";
import { InputText } from "./component/InputText";
import { useState } from "react";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  buttonsContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    flex: "0 0 auto",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    marginTop: 8
  }
}));

const initialValues = {
  movie: ""
};

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  movie: Yup.string().required("Required")
});

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [addMovie, setAddMovie] = useState(false);

  function _onSubmit(fields, { props, setErrors, setSubmitting }) {
    console.log(fields);
    setSubmitting(false);
    setAddMovie(false);
  }

  return (
    <Box className="App">
      <h1>Validation schema with Formik and Yup</h1>
      <h2>How disable validation Formik when clicking cancel button?</h2>
      <Formik
        enableReinitialize={true}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={_onSubmit}
      >
        {function Render({
          errors,
          touched,
          isSubmitting,
          setFieldValue,
          handleChange,
          resetForm,
          setErrors
        }) {
          return (
            <>
              {addMovie ? (
                <Box display="flex" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
                  <Form
                    id="form"
                    style={{
                      border: "1px solid gray",
                      padding: 16,
                      paddingBottom: 32
                    }}
                    maxWidth="500px"
                  >
                    <Grid container direction="row">
                      <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <h2>Form</h2>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Field
                          name="movie"
                          component={InputText}
                          label="Movie"
                          autoFocus
                          disabled={isSubmitting}
                        />
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Box className={classes.buttonsContainer}>
                          <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
                            <Box mr={2}>
                              <Button
                                variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                fullWidth
                                type="submit"
                                form="form"
                                disabled={isSubmitting}
                              >
                                Submit
                              </Button>
                            </Box>
                            <Button
                              fullWidth
                              variant="outlined"
                              disabled={isSubmitting}
                              onClick={() => {
                                resetForm();
                                setAddMovie(false);
                              }}
                            >
                              Cancel
                            </Button>
                          </Box>
                        </Box>
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </Form>
                </Box>
              ) : (
                <Grid container direction="row">
                  <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <Box className={classes.buttonsContainer}>
                      <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
                        <Box mr={2}>
                          <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            fullWidth
                            disabled={isSubmitting}
                            onClick={() => {
                              setAddMovie(true);
                            }}
                          >
                            Add Movie
                          </Button>
                        </Box>
                      </Box>
                    </Box>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              )}
            </>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by passing `validateOnBlur={false}` to Formik.

**Before:**

[image: Before solved]

**After:**

[image: After soved]

```
<Formik
        enableReinitialize={true}
        validateOnBlur={false}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={_onSubmit}
 >
```

[image]

Comment: Solves the issue with jumping elements when you want to click them, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it is caused by the autofocus prop on your Field. Turns out that the field validation intercepts the event to leave the form since it considers that the form isn't untouched (you technically selected a field). I haven't found a workaround this yet but you could look into using the pristine prop from Formik. Hope this helps!

```
<Formik
    enableReinitialize={true}
    initialValues={initialValues}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    onSubmit={_onSubmit}
  >
    {({
      errors,
      touched,
      pristine
      isSubmitting,
      setFieldValue,
      handleChange,
      resetForm,
      setErrors
    }) => (
       <Form>
         <Field
           name="movie"
           component={InputText}
           label="Movie"
           disabled={isSubmitting}
         />
       </Form>
    )}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I couldn't reproduce your solution, can you implement it in CodeSandbox? follow the link to make the fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/validation-schema-with-formik-and-yup-90lxm0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/validation-schema-with-formik-and-yup-forked-vxcn77?file=/src/App.js

This works for me if you enter the form and click cancel or if you select the field, enter something in it and click cancel. The only case it doesn't work is if you select the field without writing anything in it and click cancel.

Comment: I understand, removing the `autoFocus` from the field solves partial, however I need to keep the `autoFocus` in my forms, how can I use this `pristine` function of the formik that you commented?

Comment: I have a similar problem I think. I have a mui Stepper. If I press the Back Button on a Step then its onClick is NOT called and instead I see that the field in the Step fails its Yup vaidation (required). A 2nd click of the Back button works as expected.

So it appears that Formik or Yup is intercepting the Button click event (as mentioned above), and so the onClick does not fire (on first click). How to solve?

I do not have autoFocus set on the field